# How do I show that $n$ is prime if and only if $\phi(n) = n − 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, prime-numbers, totient-function

I am trying to construct a proof that shows both the 'forward' and 'backward' directions for the statement

> $n$ is prime if and only if $\phi(n) = n − 1$,

however I cannot figure out what specific proof type to use for both directions.

Thanks.

Comment: If $n$ is prime, use the definition of "$n$ is prime", together with the _definition_ of $\phi(n)$ to show $\phi(n)=n-1$.

Comment: When can the number of numbers in the range $[1,n-1]$ that are coprime to $n$, be just $n-1$ ? Apparently only if no number in this range except $1$ divides $n$.

Comment: For a prime $n$, every integer in the set $\{1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$ are relatively prime (coprime) to $n$. Therefore, $$\phi(n) = n-1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the forward direction, you need to show that if $n$ is prime then $\phi(n)=n-1$, i.e. the only number in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which has a nontrivial common factor with $n$ is $n$ itself.

For the backward direction, you need to check that whenever $n$ is not prime, either there are at least two numbers in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which have a nontrivial common factor with $n$, or there are none. (These correspond to the two cases $n$ composite and $n=1$.)

Comment: Would you be able to expand for the backward direction? I have that if 'n' is composite, then there exists an 'a' such that gcd(n,a)=b>1. However, would the assumption that 'n' is composite require a contradiction or contrapositive proof?

Comment: Yes, that's enough as it means that if $n$ is composite $\phi(n)\leq n-2$, so $\phi(n)\neq n-1$. This is a contrapositive proof: what you wanted was $\phi(n)=n-1$ implies $n$ is prime, so "$n$ is not prime implies $\phi(n)\neq n-1$" is the contrapositive.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry, but where does the n-2 come from?

Comment: @Jack we know $\gcd(a,n)>1$ and $\gcd(n,n)>1$. Of the numbers $1$ to $n$, at least $2$ have $\gcd(k,n)>1$ so at most $n-2$ have $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

Answer (score 5):

If $n$ is prime then any number less than $n$ is coprime to $n$.  There are $n-1$ such numbers.

Conversely if $\phi(n)=n-1$, then all of the numbers less than $n$ are coprime to $n$, which means $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by $\phi(n)$, with $n$ a positive integer, you mean Euler's totient function, which counts how many integers from 1 to $n$ are coprime to $n$. Algebraically: $$\phi(n) = \sum_{i = i}^n \delta_1^{\gcd(i, n)},$$ where $\delta_b^a$ is the Kronecker delta function.

Except for $n = 1$, no positive integer $n$ is coprime to itself. So if you don't know whether $n$ is prime or not, you can provisionally write down $¿ \phi(n) = n - 1 ?$. Then check if $n$ is divisible by 2. If it is, then that means $n$ is not coprime to even integers and we now have $$¿ \phi(n) = \frac{n}{2} ?$$ If $n$ is a positive composite even number, then clearly $$\phi(n) \leq \frac{n}{2} < (n - 1).$$

If instead $n$ is a positive composite odd number, it must be divisible by some positive odd prime $p < n$. Then $$\phi(n) \leq \left(n - \frac{n}{p}\right) < (n - 1).$$

Well, I think you get the idea.

---

Here's a little tidbit you might find interesting: $\phi(6) < \sqrt 6$. Generally $\phi(n) > \sqrt n$.